# How to filter list value in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm new to this site and to Python and this question may be a bit basic.

I have a pandas Series that contains a list of elements in each row and I am trying to filter each list to only keep the elements in a given list.

```
reference_list = [item_a, item_c]

index       answers
 1       [item_a, item_b, item_c]
 2       [item_c, item_d, item_e]
 3       [item_a, item_c, item_b]
```

The output I am looking for would look like this

```
index       answers
 1       [item_a, item_c]
 2       [item_c]
 3       [item_a, item_c]
```

So far I have tried `for` loops, `pd.Series.apply(lambda x:)` functions and comprehension lists but I did not get the result I needed.

If anyone could give me further insights on my mistakes I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Though you'll find answers to this, having lists inside dataframes is usually a design error. It's hard to work with them and you lose much of pandas functionalities since it expects atomic values in the cells. You should probably have a column with unique item ID and another with an item group (like "A", "B", "C").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `map` with list check

```
df['new'] = df.answers.map(lambda x : [y for y in x if y in reference_list])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
df['answers'] = df['answers'].apply(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: y in set(reference_list), x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Used the 'np.in1d' function from numpy to filter.

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(0, len(df['answers'])):
    df.iat[i, 0] = np.array(df.iat[i, 0])[np.in1d(df.iat[i, 0], reference_list)]
```

Output

```
            answers
1  [item_a, item_c]
2          [item_c]
3  [item_a, item_c]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either overwrite the column with the filtered column or create a new one:

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame( {"answers":[ [1,2,3,4],[1,4],[1,3,42]] })

# keep only odd elements, put them into "filtered"
df["filtered"] = df["answers"].apply(lambda v : [a for a in v if a%2==1])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
        answers   filtered
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]     [1, 3]
1        [1, 4]        [1]
2    [1, 3, 42]     [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `set` is another option:

```
reference_set = set(reference_list)
df['new'] = df.answers.map(set).map(lambda x: x&reference_set).map(list)

>>> df
'''
                    answers               new
1  [item_a, item_b, item_c]  [item_a, item_c]
2  [item_c, item_d, item_e]          [item_c]
3  [item_a, item_c, item_b]  [item_a, item_c]
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe U can use the function where.

[pandas.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)
Have a nice day